# Recovery Console Does Not Find My Windows Installations

Tags: bsod, console

Hi i have a BSOD when booting into windows. 
I want to perform a chkdsk to fix any bad sectors etc.
I insert win xp cd and boot from cd, i press r to access the recovery console.

The harddrive....

The hard drive has 4 different partitions....
1 = qbservice - must be volume full of default utilities
2 = Windows partition
3 = Data partions acts as secondary drive
4 = Back/Restore drive

When the recovery console starts it only display a windows installion inside partition 1!
Why is it now picking up the installation inside partition 2!?

- Note - The laptop is an Acer Aspire 6920g with Vista - I'm using a win xp to get to recovery console so surely this shouldn't cause a problem....

Next questions - Lets say i cant use the recovery console.. Is there any sort of bootable cd that contains chkdsk? If there is then does chkdsk need to be able to find the windows installations? Surely not?

Comment: Since there is only one legitimate windows partition, it is showing you that one, your question is not clear. "Why now" does not tell us much about what you are seeing and when. If you can log onto the windows installation and get a command prompt in RC, you are in the correct partition, run the chkdsk.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to guess that possibly the WinXp CD does not have the needed drivers for something in your HDD controller. I would definitely give a 3rd party a shot on this one, like the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to recover a non-booting XP installation.   On my first run of the XP recovery console, it did not list any partitions or windows installations, but it did give me a RC prompt. I ran chkdsk, which reported fixing errors.   Upon rebooting and re-running RC (XP still didn't boot), it then offered to log me in to a windows installation.

So you may need to run chkdsk to repair your disk before you will see all your partitions in RC.